# Italicize JavaScript's reserved keywords in VS Code

Tags: javascript, textmate, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to create custom syntax styling with [Visual Studio Code's theme settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) via [TextMate language grammars](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars).

Specifically, I'm wanting to italicize all of JavaScript's reserved keywords. I've managed to get 98% of the way there with the settings below (comments included for what's left).

Unfortunately, there are a few rules I wasn't able to find:

1. `storage` includes the fat arrow symbol, which I do **not** want to include. I tried to be more specific, as seen in the settings below, but was unable to find more specific settings for `constructor` and `const`. Additionally, `"storage.type.function"` was the most explicit setting I could find for functions (needed for the function keyword, but it includes the fat arrow).
2. `keyword` includes characters such as logical operators, etc., which again, I do **not** want to include. `keyword.operator` is necessary for the textual operators (e.g. `in`, `instanceof`), but includes the character operators.
3. I wasn't able to find rules for `eval` (disallowed in strict) or `package` (unused future keyword).

Any ideas?

```
const settings = {
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          // TODO: missing keywords: package, eval

      // all comment types
      "comment",

      // true, false, null
      "constant.language",

      // import, from, export, default, return, if, for, break, continue, try, catch, finally,
      // throw, default, yield, await
      "keyword.control",

      // TODO: remove operator symbols
      // in, void, delete, instanceof
      "keyword.operator",

      // debugger
      "keyword.other",

      // new
      "keyword.operator.new",

      // enum
      "storage.type.enum",

      // super, this, arguments
      "variable.language",

      // attributes in html, jsx, etc.
      "entity.other.attribute-name",

      // TODO: remove storage.type after finding explicit for constructor, const, let, var
      "storage.type",

      // static, extends, async, private, public, implements
      "storage.modifier",

      // TODO: exclude fat arrow
      // function
      "storage.type.function",

      // class
      "storage.type.class",

      // interface
      "storage.type.interface",
    ],
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": "italic"
    }
  },
]
  },
};
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As it turns out, in VS Code you can easily find the scope you need.

Open up the command search with <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and search for `Developer: Inspect TM scopes`. You can then click to the left of any symbol/word you'd like to find the scope to.

---

To answer my own question:

1. So far, there is not an explicit scope for `const`, `let`, `var` or the `function` keyword by itself (`storage.type.function` includes the reserved word and the arrow). There is, however, an explicit scope for the function arrow: `storage.type.function.arrow`. This allows us to include the entire `storage` scope, and then explicitly exclude the arrow.
2. `keyword.operator.expression` is the scope needed for only operators that are represented as words.
3. Specific scopes for `eval` and `package` are not yet available. You could target `eval` with `support.function` and `package` with `variable.other.readwrite`, but these scopes are broad and will include many other results.

---

With that said, the rules necessary for italicizing all of JavaScript's reserved keywords in VS Code are listed below (comments and `jsx`/`html` attributes also included):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
"textMateRules": [
  {
    "scope": [
      // all comment types
      "comment",

      // true, false, null
      "constant.language",

      // import, from, export, default, return, if, for, break, continue, try, catch, finally,
      // throw, default, yield, await
      "keyword.control",

      // in, void, delete, instanceof
      "keyword.operator.expression",

      // debugger
      "keyword.other",

      // new
      "keyword.operator.new",

      // super, this, arguments
      "variable.language",

      // attributes in html, jsx, etc.
      "entity.other.attribute-name",

      // static, extends, async, private, public, implements
      // constructor, const, let, var, enum, class, function, interface
      // no explicit scopes for constructor, const, let, var
      // also no explicit scope for function without the arrow
      // therefore we enable all storage and explictly exclude the arrow in another scope
      "storage",

      // // no explicit scope for the eval keyword yet
      // // can be targeted with the scope below, but scope is too broad
      // "support.function",

      // // no explicit scope for the package keyword yet
      // // can be targeted with the scope below, but scope is too broad
      // "variable.other.readwrite",
    ],
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": "italic"
    }
  },
  {
    "scope": [
      // function keyword does not have an explicit scope without the arrow
      // therefore we explictly exclude the function arrow from being italicized
      "storage.type.function.arrow",
    ],
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": ""
    }
  }
]
  }
```

Comment: You can also refer to this list - https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars